# PHP HTTP Post Server - can't get post requests

Tags: php, http, post, request

So I'm working on a group project for school, and we're working with a client who wants a companion app of sorts to go with his companies device. We provide the device a host IP or domain and it sends HTTP Post requests in the form of XML every 5 seconds or so. The problem we're having is we have NO idea how to capture the data being sent on our server. Simply trying to grab and dump all $_POST data yields an empty array, and our attempts to use a socket have produced similar results.

We've tried pointing the device to http://posttestserver.com/ - and it gets the data perfectly, though there is no source code available to see how the site operates. Admittedly our knowledge of server side scripting is limited at best as we've only been working with PHP for a couple months, and this isn't something that has been covered.

The above mentioned post server produces the following output ( with some omitted data for privacy ). Any help in reproducing this or simply assistance in getting the data on our server would be greatly appreciated!

```
Time: Sun, 09 Nov 14 14:20:26 -0800
Source ip: ######

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REMOTE_PORT = ######
REMOTE_ADDR = ######
CONTENT_LENGTH = 488
CONTENT_TYPE = application/xml
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Raven Uploader/v1
HTTP_FROM = ######
HTTP_ACCEPT = */*
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
HTTPS = on
UNIQUE_ID = VF-oqtBx6hIAACKZ7j0AAAAH
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1415571626.7993
REQUEST_TIME = 1415571626

No Post Params.

== Begin post body ==
<?xml version="1.0"?><clientcompany macId="######" version="1.1" timestamp="1415571625s">
<PriceCluster>
  <DeviceMacId>######</DeviceMacId>
  <MeterMacId>######</MeterMacId>
  <TimeStamp>0x1bf2a52d</TimeStamp>
  <Price>0x00000467</Price>
  <Currency>0x007c</Currency>
  <TrailingDigits>0x04</TrailingDigits>
  <Tier>0x01</Tier>
  <StartTime>0x1bf2a52d</StartTime>
  <Duration>0xffff</Duration>
  <RateLabel>Block 2</RateLabel>
</PriceCluster>

</clientcompany>

== End post body ==

Upload contains PUT data:
<?xml version="1.0"?><clientcompany macId="0xd8d5b90016d1" version="1.1" timestamp="1415571625s">
<PriceCluster>
  <DeviceMacId>######</DeviceMacId>
  <MeterMacId>######</MeterMacId>
  <TimeStamp>0x1bf2a52d</TimeStamp>
  <Price>0x00000467</Price>
  <Currency>0x007c</Currency>
  <TrailingDigits>0x04</TrailingDigits>
  <Tier>0x01</Tier>
  <StartTime>0x1bf2a52d</StartTime>
  <Duration>0xffff</Duration>
  <RateLabel>Block 2</RateLabel>
</PriceCluster>

</clientcompany>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the raw input stream:

```
//$data = $_POST; <-- will be empty unless you are sending a key value pair(s)
$data = file_get_contents('php://input'); //<-- will capture all posted data
echo '== Begin post body ==';   
echo $data;
echo '== End post body ==';
```

If you need to see headers as well you can use `getallheaders` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: This definitely sounds like what needs to be done.. but the server still isn't getting anything. I've got this running in a file called post.php and am pointing the device to ip/post.php. ( same as we did with the above site that worked ). Is there anything else I need to do to get this to work - a broad question I know. Thanks!

Comment: @echo How are you checking the response from the website? Perhaps you should log $data to a file? Without seeing how you are sending the post request it's very hard to help.

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to mark this as the accepted answer, it was essentially what I needed to do. There were some permissions I needed to setup on my server to get it all working correctly though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of $_POST check $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA var

Comment: `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is depreciated: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Comment: a long time ago used it ;)